# swfobject: Absolute position link over flash in all PC browsers

Tags: html, css, flash, swfobject

I have a number of flash ads (installed with swfobject) which have an HTML link placed over the top of them. I am using wmode transparent and it works fine in every browser on mac  however ie/chrome/ff on PC (viewing on win7) the link falls behind the flash.

I have also tried wmode=opaque to no avail.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="$Link" class="overlay"></a>
<div class="flashContainerSml">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="125" height="125">
    <param name="movie" value="$Flash.URL" />
    <param  name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="$Flash.URL" width="125" height="125">
    <param  name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <p>no flash</p>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</div>
```

and the appropriate css

```
#sideBar .smallAd .overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple in the end. Notice the transparent gif in the link.

```
<a href="$Link" class="overlay"><img src="$ThemeDir/images/transparent.gif" /></a>
                        <div class="flashContainerSml">
                            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="125" height="125">
                            <param name="movie" value="$Flash.URL" />
                            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                            <!--[if !IE]>-->
                            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="$Flash.URL" width="125" height="125">
                            <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
                            <!--<![endif]-->
                              <p></p>
                            <!--[if !IE]>-->
                            </object>
                            <!--<![endif]-->
                            </object>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason that the button/link isn't in the swf itself? It's bad practice to be stacking a button on top of a swf like that(as you have found out). If I were you, I would redo the swf so you can put the button inside rather than trying to stack on top.

Comment: Agree it's not ideal. The ads are uploaded to the CMS by a client and their sources sometimes don't embed a link within the ad so we gave them the ability to specify a link in the CMS.

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you for explaining your situation a bit more. I will post another solution.

Answer (score 1):

If option 1 (my first answer) doesn't work, try this solution:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    swfobject.embedSWF("flash/movie.swf", "no-flash", "195", "120",
    "9.0.0", "flash/expressInstall.swf", {}, {wmode:"transparent"}, {});

    $('#div2').live('click',function() {
      alert('triggered a click');
    });
  });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  #div {
    position:relative;
  }
  #div2 {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>  

<div id="div">
  <div id="div2" style="width:195px;height:120px;">
    <object type="img/gif">
      <img src="images/null.gif" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </object>
  </div>   

  <img id="no-flash" src="images/no-flash.gif" alt="" />  

 </div>
```

I’ve put the #div2 div within the first div this time, but above the image that is being replaced by SWFObject. Inside this div is an Object tag with the MIME type set to “img/gif”, and then obviously just an image within the object tag. This image is just a 1×1 transparent gif. Therefore the Object with the image will be above the other due to DOM order and z-indexes.
This will now successfully trigger the alert on all the browsers I require.. FireFox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer 8, Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 6.

Comment: I was inspired by your mention of a transparent gif. I decided to try putting some text in the empty 'a' tag and it worked so I swapped the text for a transparent gif and it solved it